# Odd IE9/7 style issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

So i am completely baffled by this and hoping someone can give me some ideas to try. Not sure what details to include so let me know if i dont describe it enough and i'll add more.

We inherited a .Net MVC 4 app from a former company that already has a version on our clients production server. Recently, after a few updates from us, our client noticed that some of the menu items, styling, etc is screwed up on their test and QA servers in IE9 but works on production (Production is still from the previous companies publish). The test and QA versions also work fine in FF and Chrome

Using IETester and IE11, I tried viewing the page in IE9 mode but I did not see the same issues that my client is having, so i tried some older versions out of curiosity. I managed to reproduce the issue, but in IE7 not IE9. I had my client verify that he is in fact using IE9 and he is.

I did a compare with older versions of our _Layout.cshtml and there isnt a single thing that changed other than a favico entry. As far as i can tell, we havent changed any css or styling.

I have a webex meeting with the client tomorrow to look at his IE to see if i can find anything, but can anyone give me some ideas of what could cause this? Particularly that this page works in my IE9 but not his?

Comment: What kind of styling issues? and are they doing automation for testing?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer to your question, but I do want to point out that IE Tester uses emulation to give you the closest representation of what your page will look like in older versions of IE, but it is never exact. I would try getting an actual version of IE9 running in a VM to see what it really looks like.

Comment: IE9 can be configured to force pages to be rendered as if the browser were really IE7.  That can be through explicit local configuration, or through corporate rules. Look into [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that the sort of environment where people are used to seeing everything the way it looked in IE7 is not likely to be the sort of environment where any individual would know or care what's going on.

Comment: @Pointy - Corporate rules would makes sense as this is a large company with plenty of standards in place and they do have lots of older webapps requiring older browsers, however if that were the case, wouldn't the version on their production server not work as well? I know you can set different settings per site, but figured they would just globally set rules. APAD1 - Yeah i am working with our QA dept to get an older VM =-)

Comment: Well there must be *some* difference in the code, or else possibly the production servers are configured to include an `X-UA-Compatible` directive as an HTTP header, while the test servers are not.

Comment: So we just confirmed it was indeed set to IE7 when they go to QA and Test but sets the mode to 9 for production. We still cant figure out how this changed but I have a feeling it might be something their network policy has set but not 100% sure. Im trying to avoid using X-UA-Compatible if possible but he has to change the document mode every time now. I did notice that production has the html5 tag <!DOCTYPE html> - would that cause IE to change modes? I wouldnt think so but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you set  the default browser mode to be **ie7** and the document mode to be **ie9 standard** and you try again to change the browser mode to be **ie9 compat view**  then unfortunately the browser version will be detected as ie7 , the solution for this problem is to change the browser mode to be ie9 but not **ie9 compat view** then the browser version will be detected as **ie9**